# Unable to deploy webservice on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0

I am getting the following error(also see the screenshot) while trying to deploy my webservice on the server. Cant figure out the reason. Please help!!

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details 
and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebServices.WebService'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService.asmx.cs" Class="WebServices.WebService" %>

Source File: /WebServices/WebService.asmx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

[image]

Comment: Is it working locally on your machine ?!

Comment: yes its working locally but not on remote. What should be done?Thanks for reply!!

Comment: see the link i specified below, it covers all the checks needed to ensure that your webservice work properly on your server

Comment: I saw this link before too but couldnt figure out the issue.. Is my classname correct? Can that be the issue?

Comment: I think the class name might be the issue, so you must ensure that the class name in the code behind is "WebServices.WebService" so this means that you class name is WebService and it is inside a namespace called WebServices

Comment: This is how my classname is..

<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService.asmx.cs" Class="WebServices.WebService" %>

Comment: what the code behind look like ?!

Comment: This is how it is:
namespace WebServices
{
    
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Name="WebService")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
[17/05/12 3:43:34 PM] rajesh sajwani: <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService.asmx.cs" Class="WebServices.WebService" %>

Comment: Great!! was it because the class name ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a list of a checklist that you should do to make sure that your webservice work properly on your server:

http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=133

Comment: The problem was that I needed to create a virtual directory on the server and I was creating it on IIS manager. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the names: Your namespace is WebServices or WebService? Class name is correct?

I suggest you to create fresh web service without any code and try to deploy. Then add some of your code there and deploy again.

Comment: Namespace:WebSerices
Classname:WebService.asmx.cs

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Please verify also Application Pool configurations. Try to change it to different value and invoke the web service. Config file is in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the class name (and not only the file name as i can see on your example) according to the declaration:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MyNameSpace.MyClass" %>
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
```

When the WebService derived class is declared like that:

```
namespace MyNameSpace

public class MyClass: WebService {
```

}

Comment: This is how I have written
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService.asmx.cs" Class="WebServices.WebService" %>

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService

Classname is : WebService, is this a problem? conflicting with keyword?

Comment: I guess that the file name is not the problem here... maybe the namespace then... make sure that to write a namespace for your class and that you have this definition with the correct namespace: lass="MyNameSpace.MyClass" %>

Comment: The problem was that I needed to create a virtual directory on the server and I was creating it on IIS manager. Thanks a lot!!!